# AWS CLI - How do I list instances and dump two specific tags along with other items

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

The cli below works perfectly now I would also like to capture two other tags in addition to 'Name' called 'Application' and 'Environment'. How can I change this to add Application and Environment tags to the out-put.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].
  [Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,
   State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason,Tags[?Key=='Name'] 
   | [0].Value]" --output table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html#options) to your query:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].
  [Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,InstanceType,Platform,
   State.Name,PrivateIpAddress,StateTransitionReason]" 
    --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=my-name" "Name=tag:env,Values=prod" 
     --output table"
```

This will return only the instances tagged with `Name == my-name` and `env == prod`

Comment: MrDuk thank you very much for your feedback so my intent is not to filter out anything but to get the additional tags of environment and that of function as additional col. So I want a way to modify my original query to add additional tags. So this part of the query Tags[?Key=='Name'] | [0].Value] displays the Name tag as a col so all the instances will show what their respective name. I want those other two tags also displayed as col such that each row will show an instance per row with all the information associated with the instance as defined in the query.